# Convergence with Cauchy Sequences Proof.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a sequence that satisfies $$|a_n - a_m| \leq  \frac{2}{m + \sqrt{n}}  \forall m,n.$$ Prove that $a_n$ is convergent.

I understand that the def. for Cauchy sequences is for every $\varepsilon > 0,\exists N$ such that for every $m,n>N \implies |a_n - a_m| < \varepsilon$.    So, could I let $\varepsilon =  \frac{2}{m + \sqrt{n}}$ and then say that the sequence is Cauchy and therefore convergent?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $$|a_n - a_m| < \frac{2}{m}.$$

So take $\varepsilon > 0$ and N such that $2/N < \varepsilon;$ then, if $n,m\ge N,$ $|a_n-a_m| < \varepsilon,$

so $a$ is a Cauchy sequence and therefore convergent.

Comment: That is so simple! Thank you.